# Delphi 8. Запись в файл русских символов -> Чтение из файла -> Вывод в ListBox -> Кракозябры

Tags: delphi, кодировка

Облазил уже кучу форумов, но ничего интересного не нашел... Проблема такова:
Я сохраняю в текстовый файл текст, где могут быть и русские буквы, потом читаю и, когда вывожу в listbox выводятся кракозябры. Как я понял в ListBox надо выводить в Ansi. А в файлы почему-то сохраняется в кодировке UTF-8, хотя на форумах писали, что стандартная кодировка это Ansi. Лазил по настройкам ничего похожего не нашел:) Видел функцию UTF8ToAnsi, но почему-то у меня пишет Undeclared identifier. Может надо какую-то библиотеку подключить? Подскажите, что можно сделать?

Чтение и запись самые обычные assign -> rewrite/reset -> closefile... на всякий случай код:

IDE - Borland Delphi 8
запись

```
procedure WritelnNewTest(T:TTest);
var
FOut: TextFile;
ShareDir: AnsiString;
I, J: Integer;
begin
  ShareDir := CDir + '\Tests\' + T.FileName;
  if DirectoryExists(ShareDir) then DeleteDir(ShareDir);
  MkDir(ShareDir);
  Assign(FOut, ShareDir + '.test');
  Rewrite(FOut);
    WriteLn(FOut, T.Name);
    WriteLn(FOut, T.Time);
    WriteLn(FOut, T.NQ);
    for I := 0 to T.NQ - 1 do
    begin
      WriteLn(FOut, Integer(T.Questions[I].QImg));
      if T.Questions[I].QImg = TRUE then
      begin
        WriteLn(FOut, T.Questions[I].PImg);
        CopyFile(T.Questions[I].PImg, ShareDir + '\' + ExtractFileName(T.Questions[I].PImg), TRUE);
      end;
      WriteLn(FOut, Integer(T.Questions[I].QText));
      if T.Questions[I].QText then WriteLn(FOut, T.Questions[I].Text);
      WriteLn(FOut, T.Questions[I].NAns);
      for J := 0 to T.Questions[I].NAns - 1 do
      begin
        WriteLn(FOut, T.Questions[I].Answers[J].Text);
        WriteLn(FOut, T.Questions[I].Answers[J].Balls);
      end;
    end;
  CloseFile(FOut);
end;
```

чтение

```
function ReadTestInfo(DirFile: String):TTest;
var
Fin: TextFile;
T: TTest;
I, J: Integer;
X: Integer;
begin
  AssignFile(FIn, DirFile);
  Reset(FIn);
    ReadLn(FIn, T.Name);
    ReadLn(FIn, T.Time);
    ReadLn(FIn, T.NQ);
    SetLength(T.Questions, T.NQ);
    for I := 0 to T.NQ -1 do
    begin
      ReadLn(FIn, X);
      T.Questions[I].QImg := Boolean(X);
      if (T.Questions[I].QImg) then ReadLn(FIn, T.Questions[I].PImg);//read img path
      ReadLn(FIn, X);
      T.Questions[I].QText := Boolean(X);
      if (T.Questions[I].QText) then Readln(FIn, T.Questions[I].Text);//read text
      ReadLn(FIn, T.Questions[I].NAns);
      SetLength(T.Questions[I].Answers, T.Questions[I].NAns);
      for J := 0 to T.Questions[I].NAns - 1 do
      begin
        ReadLn(FIn, T.Questions[I].Answers[J].Text);
        ReadLn(FIn, T.Questions[I].Answers[J].Balls);
      end;
    end;
  CloseFile(FIn);
  ReadTestInfo := T;
end;
```

тип TTest

```
TAnswer = record
    Text: AnsiString;
    Balls: LongInt;
  end;
  TAnswerArray = Array of TAnswer;

  TQuestion = record
    QImg, QText: Boolean; //Question text, Question Image
    PImg: AnsiString; //Path to img
    NAns: Integer;
    Text: AnsiString;
    Answers: TAnswerArray;
  end;
  TQuestionsArray = Array of TQuestion;

  TTest = record
    FileName, Name: AnsiString;
    Time: LongInt;
    NQ: Integer; //Number of Questions
    Questions: TQuestionsArray;
    Ril: Integer;
  end;
  TTestsArray = Array of TTest;
```

Решение найдено:
http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?bid=20&tid=898323

Comment: Поля структуры заполнются консоли? Возможно проблема в том что обычно ввод с консоли идет в кодировке 866, а листбокс показывает в кодировке 1251. Для того чтобы в листбокс отображалось нормально, нужно или установить кодировку ввода с консоли в 1251 (SetConsoleCP(1251); SetConsoleInput(1251);), или перекодировать при выводе в файл или при выводе в листбокс (функция OemToChar).

Answer (score 1):

Я предлагаю сохранять строки в файле и читать их оттуда не напрямую, а через методы самого ListBox'a.
Запись в файл:

```
ListBox1.Items.SaveToFile('имя файла');
```

Чтение из файла:

```
ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile('имя файла');
```

Comment: я думаю, что дело это не поменяет, т.к. ListBox по идеи принимает ansi, а в файл записывается utf-8. И мне нужны только некоторые строки из файла, а не все:)

Comment: Прочитанные строки, можно ведь потом удалить, обратившись к индексу. А если использовать и для сохранения списка, и для его чтения методы ListBox'a, то, это должно сохранить и считать правильно.

Comment: да, так работает, ListBox создает файл в ansi и читает из него нормально, но все же я не думаю, что это хорошее решение проблемы. просто затычка, ее использую в на худой конец:) надо же потом и записывать обратно в файлЫ их не один и обратно все забивать в ListBox и сохранять в файл с моей точки зрения кривоватый способ:) но действующий:)

Comment: `SaveToFile` и `LoadFromFile` это методы не ListBox-а, а его свойства `Items`. `Items` это объект типа `TStrings`. Если нужно читать/писать в файлы независимо от `ListBox`, можно в runtime создать объект типа `TStringList` наполнить его списком и воспользоваться теми же методами - `SaveToFile` и `LoadFromFile`.

Comment: Я тоже хотел предложить использование TStringList, но не посчитал это необходимым.